# How to POST to a "textarea" with NSURLConnection?

Tags: html, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm struggling to figure out how to interface to this block of `HTML` on a website I'm interacting with through Objective-C.  The webpage has a text area that you can type in and it has a submit button under it.  The `HTML` looks like this:

```
<fieldset>

<textarea id="postbody" cols="40" rows="5" name="postbody">

This has now been taken. Thank you to everyone who has shown an interest. 

</textarea>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send TAKEN message">

</fieldset>
```

Anyway, I am trying to interface with this website using `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSString *convertedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"postbody=%@", @"This item has been received"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[convertedString UTF8String] length:strlen([convertedString UTF8String])]];//this attaches the username and password key we created with convertedString to the request we just initialized
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];//we're sending information TO the site

self.safetyRequest = request;//this is to handle the possibility that the user hits back and chooses the same menu item more than once.

[self setReceivedData:[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0]];//make sure we re-initialize our data container

[self setTheConnection:[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]];//this fires off the URL request to the web!!  This is an asynchronous request, so we need to implement the delegates for NSURLConnection.
```

This, however, does not work for some reason.  The site does not respond and perform the required action of posting a response and submitting it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify "site does not respond"? Have you looked at the response received in `connection:didReceiveResponse:`? What was the `statusCode`? Did you handle errors in `connection:didFailWithError:`? Anything reported there? Even if the response was malformed, you'd expect a `didReceiveResponse` or `didFailWithError`, at the very least.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong.  I was actually posting to a URL that doesn't accept POSTing.  When you hit the submit button, it actually posts that information to a different URL.  Once I found that out, everything worked just fine.  Thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should percent-escape the data you post, which you can do with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, such as:

```
NSString *convertedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postbody=%@", [self percentEscapeString:@"This item has been received"]];
[request setHTTPBody:[convertedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Where you have a method that calls `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

Comment: Probably needless to point out, but using framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) gets you out of the weeds of constructing well-formed `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. It's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Handle your result data with help of NSURLConnection delegate methods

```
  NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"postBody=%@",@"Raja"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/promos/index.php"]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){
        // indicator.hidden = NO;
        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
```

your PHP code

```
<?php
    $result = $_POST['postBody'];


    echo $result;
?>
```